# Insert data into PHP StdClass Object

Tags: php

We inserted data into PHP StdClass Object.

But there are key duplicates.

What is the reason?

print_r($result)

result :

```
stdClass Object ( 
    [0] => stdClass Object ( 
        [_id] => MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId Object ( [oid] => 59e2ff28da721533d277792c ) 
        [title] => "TEST"
    ) 
)
```

$result->{0}->ww = "C";

```
Warning: Creating default object from empty value in /var/www/html/httpapi/all.php on line 61

stdClass Object ( 
    [0] => stdClass Object ( 
        [_id] => MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId Object ( [oid] => 59e2ff28da721533d277792c ) 
        [title] => "TEST" 
    ) 
    [0] => stdClass Object ( [ww] => C )
)
```

Comment: Where does `$result` come from?

Comment: I'd convert that to an array, eg `$resultArr = (array) $result;`

Comment: $result from is mongodb query result